# gdb not giving reason for core dump

Tags: c, linux, gdb, coredump

Typically when analyzing a core dump in gdb it'll print the reason why it was generated:

```
Core was generated by `executable'.
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
```

However I've encountered a situation where gdb isn't giving a reason:

```
Core was generated by `executable'.
```

I'm wondering what could cause a core dump where gdb doesn't give the reason for its generation.

Comment: Are you compiling with `-g -O0`?

Comment: The executable that generated the core dump was compiled with just -O3 and not -g. I recompiled using the same source with -O3 and -g in order to use gdb with the symbol table.

Comment: Does the shell command `file corefilename` show the termination reason?

Comment: Running that gives me: `ELF 64-bit LSB  core file x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), SVR4-style, from 'executable'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this core file was generated using gcore, so there wasn't actually a problem with the executable. /facepalm